# Sending List Box search results to a Table

Tags: ms-access, vba

Ok so i painfully made this code, and it works, but its slow and crashes access after a few hundred iterations. I have a multi coloumn list box showing the results of a database search. i want to take those results and put it in a temp Table called "MailingListTemp" on the click of a command button. is there a way to make this go faster and not crash or alternative methods? the end result is exporting the list to excel.

Thanks. Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub AllToMailingListCommand_Click()
        Dim i As Variant
        Dim Item As Variant
        Dim var0Search As Variant
        Dim var1Search As Variant
        Dim var2Search As Variant
        Dim var3Search As Variant
        Dim var4Search As Variant
        Dim var5Search As Variant
        Dim var6Search As Variant
        Dim var7Search As Variant
        Dim var8Search As Variant
        Dim var9Search As Variant
        Dim var10Search As Variant
        Dim var11Search As Variant
        Dim var12Search As Variant
        Dim strX As String
        Dim DValue As String
        DValue = " "
        DValue = Format(date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

        Dim dbThisDatabase As DAO.Database
        Dim rstMailingListTemp As DAO.Recordset

        Set dbThisDatabase = CurrentDb
        Set rstMailingListTemp = dbThisDatabase.OpenRecordset("MailingListTemp")


        For i = 0 To Me.List0.ListCount

        Me.List0.Selected(i) = True
        For Each Item In List0.ItemsSelected

        var0Search = List0.Column(0, Item)
        var1Search = List0.Column(1, Item)
        var2Search = List0.Column(4, Item)
        var3Search = List0.Column(5, Item)
        Next

        var4Search = DLookup("[FirstName]", "[Master Marketing List]", "[MMLID] = " & var0Search)
        var5Search = DLookup("[LastName]", "[Master Marketing List]", "[MMLID] = " & var0Search)
        var6Search = DLookup("[Zip]", "[Master Marketing List]", "[MMLID] = " & var0Search)
        var7Search = DLookup("[Address1]", "[Master Marketing List]", "[MMLID] = " & var0Search)
        var8Search = DLookup("[Address2]", "[Master Marketing List]", "[MMLID] = " & var0Search)
        var9Search = DLookup("[Address3]", "[Master Marketing List]", "[MMLID] = " & var0Search)
        var10Search = DLookup("[Prefix]", "[Master Marketing List]", "[MMLID] = " & var0Search)
        var11Search = DLookup("[Suffix]", "[Master Marketing List]", "[MMLID] = " & var0Search)
        var12Search = DLookup("[Title]", "[Master Marketing List]", "[MMLID] = " & var0Search)

        rstMailingListTemp.AddNew
        rstMailingListTemp("ID").value = var0Search
        rstMailingListTemp("CompanyName").value = var1Search
        rstMailingListTemp("City").value = var2Search
        rstMailingListTemp("State").value = var3Search
        rstMailingListTemp("FirstName").value = var4Search
        rstMailingListTemp("LastName").value = var5Search
        rstMailingListTemp("Zip").value = var6Search
        rstMailingListTemp("Address1").value = var7Search
        rstMailingListTemp("Address2").value = var8Search
        rstMailingListTemp("Address3").value = var9Search
        rstMailingListTemp("Prefix").value = var10Search
        rstMailingListTemp("Suffix").value = var11Search
        rstMailingListTemp("Title").value = var12Search

        rstMailingListTemp.Update

        Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using a listbox as a subform?

Answer (score 1):

You state "multi coloumn list box showing the results of a database search."  How is that search filtered into the list box?  Are you creating a SQL Where clause on the fly using various search criteria?   If so then ignore the rstMailingListTemp table and indeed all your code in this subroutine.

Instead send the results of that Where clause attached to a query into your mailing list table directly into Excel using Automation and the CopyFromRecordset function.

[Modules: Transferring Records to Excel with Automation](http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0035.htm)

**Added:**   Create a string variable that looks like

"SELECT * From MailingListTable WHERE " & (insert your Where clause here)

Then put that in the Transferring records to Excel code.

Alternatively use the docmd.TransferSpreadsheet function just to get this going. And this may be sufficient for your requirements.   Note that the tablename parameter can be a string expression containing a SELECT query.

Comment: "Are you creating a SQL Where clause on the fly using various search criteria?" - Yes

Comment: "Instead send the results of that Where clause attached to a query into your mailing list table directly into Excel using Automation and the CopyFromRecordset function."     1st, how do i send the results of the where clause to a query? and 2nd, whats the rest of that mean?  -thanks

Comment: i found a way to make it faster just by taking away the Dlookups. i instead made sure all the data i needed was in the list box so i could just pull it coloumn by colounm and not have to worry about reffering to the other table. its much faster. takes a few seconds to run 10 - 20 thousand entries but hasnt crashed

Comment: Yes, that was going to be my first suggestion but I figured that using a query would be much simpler to implement.   Although the automation code can be somewhat daunting at first glance.   I should've mentioned the TransferSpreadsheet first though instead of the Automation.